# ODBC doesn't return data when using WITH clause

Tags: sql, odbc, with-clause

I'm trying to connect to SQL Developer and get data into Excel using ODBC driver, let's make the query very simple for example purposes:

```
with temp_tab as (select * from table1)
select * from temp_tab where x = y
```

It executes in SQL Developer without problems and also works in Excel when WITH clause is removed, but in the above form it fails with error

> "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed."

Do you have any idea what might be the problem with ODBC when using WITH clause?

I am using Microsoft ODBC for Oracle version 10.000.19041.01 and SQL Server version 10.00.19041.3086.

Here you can find VBA macro that I use to get the data from SQL and copy into Excel workbook. Line where error occurs is in bold:

```
'SQL query:
Dim strQuery As String
strQuery = ""
    
' Variables related to connection with SQL
Dim adoCM As ADODB.Command
Dim adoCN As ADODB.Connection
Dim adoRS As ADODB.Recordset

Set adoCN = New ADODB.Connection
    adoCN.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    adoCN.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptComplete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    adoCN.Open "Data Source=xxx", "yyy", Password

Set adoCM = New ADODB.Command
Set adoCM.ActiveConnection = adoCN

Set adoRS = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    adoCM.CommandType = adCmdText
    
    dblStartTime = Now
    strQuery = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G3").Value
    adoCM.CommandText = strQuery
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    adoCM.CommandTimeout = 3600
    Set adoRS = adoCM.Execute
    **ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G5").CopyFromRecordset adoRS**
    dblEndTime = Now - dblStartTime

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    adoCN.Close
```

Comment: Do you mean `select * from table1` works? I doubt ODBC complains, ODBC just passes the query.

Comment: Please post *how* you are running in Excel. Are you using VBA? We need full code context to help. Please see [ask].

Comment: Yes, select * from table1 works and copy results of the query to the Excel workbook, so it shouldn't be the problem with VBA macro.